# После показа рекламы admob автоматически устанавливает timeScale на 1

Tags: c#, unity3d, admob

Есть метод, который отвечает за паузу в игре. Когда пользователь включает паузу, через раз показывается межстраничная реклама. Когда реклама не показывается, всё хорошо, если же реклама показывается, во время рекламы timeScale = 0, после рекламы timeScale = 1. Почему так? Как это решить?
Вот сам метод:

```
public void ShowPause(bool enable)
    {
        if (enable)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;

            if (startGame)
            {
                pauseText.enabled = true;
            }

            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ShowsPause") >= 2)
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ShowsPause", 0);

                Add.manager.ShowIntersitialAd();
            }
            else
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ShowsPause", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ShowsPause") + 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;

            startGame = true;
        }

        uiInGameCanvas.enabled = !enable;
        pauseCanvas.enabled = enable;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты используешь Google AdMob, то при показе рекламы выполняются методы из этого скрипта.

```
public class DummyAdBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PauseGame()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        Debug.Log("Pause Game");
    }

    public void ResumeGame()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        Debug.Log("Resume Game");
    }

    public GameObject ShowAd(GameObject dummyAd, Vector3 position)
    {
       return Instantiate(dummyAd, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }

    public void DestroyAd(GameObject dummyAd)
    {
        Destroy(dummyAd);
    }
}
```

Он находится в папке Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Platforms\Unity
Если тебе надо сделать так, чтобы после всех типов реклам timeScale оставался на нуле, то просто в методе ResumeGame() удаляешь строчку Time.timeScale = 1;
Если тебе надо после конкретной рекламы, например InterstitialAd оставлять timeScale = 0, а после, например Rewarded, возвращать timeScale на 1, то тебе нужен скрипт InterstitialClient, который находится в той же папке и в методе AddClickBehavior() удаляешь AdBehaviour.ResumeGame(). Также можно у Rewarded оставлять timeScale = 0, нужен RewardingAdBaseClient, и в нем надо удалить все тот же AdBehaviour.ResumeGame().

Вот как-то так